# how do I prevent the feComposite arithmetic svgfilters changing output channel values despite having 0 in the corresponding input channel

Tags: html, svg, svg-filters

When adding an svg box of color value #800000 to an svg box with color value #008000 I find the result is not #808000.
The result turns out to be color #898500.

```
    <feComposite in="b1" in2="b2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="comp" />
```

I'm trying to implement an svg filter that will allow me to composite an image from separate color channels. I.e. I have separate red, blue and green shapes that I wish to composite an image from. Only the red channel images should impact the red channel and so on. However, what I find is that adding any red channel color, changes all other channels. 
The following svg demonstrates the addition using the svgfilter fecomposite.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200">
<defs>
    <rect id="box1" x="00" y="00" width="40" height="40" fill="#800000" opacity="1" color-rendering="optimizeQuality" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></rect>
    <rect id="box2" x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" fill="#008000" opacity="1" color-rendering="optimizeQuality" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></rect>
  <rect id="box3" x="20" y="20" width="20" height="20" fill="#808000" opacity="1" color-rendering="optimizeQuality" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></rect>
  <image id="png1" x="00" y="00" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/publitest/Red80.png" height="40" width="40" color-rendering="optimizeQuality" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></image>
  <image id="png2" x="20" y="20" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/publitest/Green80.png" height="40" width="40" color-rendering="optimizeQuality" shape-rendering="crispEdges"></image>
</defs>

<text y="12">overlayed data</text>
<g id="twoBox" transform="translate(0,15)">
    <use href="#box1" />
    <use href="#box2" />
  <use x="50" href="#box3" />
</g>


<text y="90">fused data</text>

<filter id="compArith" x="0" y="0" width="256" height="256" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feImage href="#box1" result="b1" />
    <feImage href="#box2" result="b2" />
    <feComposite in="b1" in2="b2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="comp" />
</filter>

<g id="fusedBox" transform="translate(0,95)">
    <use id="colormap" filter="url(#compArith)" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Set the colourspace to sRGB https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color-interpolation-filters

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I already have the filter above set to color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" as per your suggestion. I've also tried the alternative "linearRGB" and that doesn't work either.

Comment: On what browser? I don't think Safari supports that property.

Comment: Maybe your color-picker is using the wrong color space? When I do this in my browser (Chrome/Win10) my color picker is showing #808000